# Live account without integration key docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I don't have demo developer account, but I have the working live account without an integrator key and I want to use DocuSign REST API. How to get an integrator key on live account or how to link the working live account with demo developer account in order to go live process?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create IntegratorKey directly in PROD environment. You need to create IntegratorKey in Demo environment only, then develop your API integration in Demo. Once you are ready to move to PROD, then go through [GO Live](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live) process to promote Integrator Key to your PROD account.